# Async operations with nodegit on electron not working

Tags: javascript, electron, nodegit

I am working on a project using electron and nodegit, and I recently updated my dependencies. After solving the compatibility issues, I found two versions of nodegit and electron that work. But upon testing it, I found that async nodegit operations fail, while the synchronous ones work fine. Here's a code example that does not work:

```js
const pathToRepo = require('path').resolve(path);
Git.Repository.open(pathToRepo)
.then((repo) => {
  console.log(repo);
})
.catch( (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Upon executing it, the promise returns an error which is caught by the catch block, and upon outputting the value on the console it simple displays `true`, and gives no additional information.

Also, I had updated node from 5 to 6.3 before updating my dependencies.

### Previous:

electron-prebuilt: 0.37.8
nodegit: 0.13.0

### After updating:

electron-prebuilt: 1.2.1
nodegit: 0.14.1

**EDIT**: Solved by adding an npm script:

```
"rebuild": "npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.2.1 disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --build-from-source",
```

and running `npm run rebuild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodegit` contains a native NodeJS module, native modules must be rebuilt to target the Electron version you use them with. Instructions for rebuilding native modules can be found at http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/

Comment: I had already tried running `electron-rebuild`, and also tried using `npm` to install modules directly, both of which were documented in the link. They fail to solve the issue. To be clear the `nodegit` object is accessible from electron, so the module has been built. I am having a problem with promise-only operations.

Comment: @cynicaldevil Your problem sounds exactly like the one discussed here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5851#issuecomment-224431773 so I'd suggest double checking the parameters you used for rebuilding `nodegit` to ensure they match the Electron version you're using.

Comment: @cynicaldevil Great! Don't forget to update the target version in your NPM script when you update Electron to a different version in the future :)